# Stuck at BIOS Start Screen after Booting with Ubuntu USB Stick

Tags: ubuntu, boot, motherboard, bios, freeze

I had `ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso` installed on my computer. Today, I decided to downgrade my Ubuntu from `19` back to `18`.
So that's what I did:

1. Download `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` from here: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. Create bootable USB stick from the downloaded `ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` via "Make Startup Disk"
3. Reboot PC and enter BIOS
4. Move my USB stick to the top of the boot order

At this point my BIOS has become unresponsive (nothing happened for minutes)

After force-rebooting I am stuck at this screen:
[image]

Neither with or without the stick plugged in, it will always show this screen, forever. I can't press `DEL` or `F2`, absolutely nothing happens.

So I tried to reset my motherboard like it is described in the handbook:
[image]

1. Turn OFF the computer and unplug the power cord
2. Move the jumper cap from pins 1-2 (default) to pins 2-3. Keep the cap on pins 2-3 for about 5-10 seconds, then move the cap back to pins 1-2.
3. Plug the power cord and turn ON the computer
4. Hold down the `Del` key during boot process and enter BIOS setup to reenter data.

(I've event tried it with removing the battery, as described in the picture)

**But I've got the same issue**. Can't do anything, other than looking at this wonderful black screen with the Asus logo.

It's really strange, because I changed Ubuntu versions just like this several times without issues.

So what are my options?

P.S. When setting the boot order I noticed many different entries, even though I had only a USB stick and 3 hard drives plugged in. (strangely, there were about 12 entries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I fixed it myself: I just unplugged my HDD from my motherboard.